# Oracle SQL - group by date_format function

Tags: sql, distinct, date-format

Can someone help me to solve my error please?
I am trying to count distinct values in `ID_ACCIDENT` column and I want them grouped by months (dates are stored in column `DATUM` in format `YYYY/MM/DD`).

A the moment I have this code:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATUM, '%Y/%M') as "Month",COUNT (DISTINCT ID_ACCIDENT) AS "Počet nehod" 
FROM RAW_DATA
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATUM, '%Y/%M');
```

But it doesn't work - getting `error 00904. 00000 - invalid identifier`.

Comment: try `GROUP BY 1`

Comment: Could you please show the exact outcome you want to get? The desired date format is unclear. You should also point out if the same months from different years should be counted together or separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `to_date` since this is Oracle -

```
select to_char(to_date(datum, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'yyyy/mm')) as month,
COUNT (DISTINCT ID_ACCIDENT) as count
from raw_data
group by to_char(to_date(datum, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'yyyy/mm'))
```

Comment: Why do you want to use both to_date and to_char? The syntax of your query is incorrect.

Comment: Ya, the to_date is redundant. But its been a (bad) habit for me working on different date formates in varchar type. But that should work for any format

Answer (score 1):

if `DATUM` is date then

```sql
SELECT 
  TRUNC(DATUM, 'MONTH')  as "Month",
  COUNT (DISTINCT ID_ACCIDENT) AS "Počet nehod" 
FROM RAW_DATA
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATUM, 'MONTH');
```

if `DATUM` is string with YYYY/MM/DD format then

```sql
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(datum,1,7), 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) 
FROM raw_data 
GROUP BY substr(datum,1,7)
```